# Changing Structure of SAM database to disable LM usage

Tags: hash, password-cracking, ntlm, samba

SAM database normally holds LM and NTLM hashes of local computer.  Recently we applied configurations for disabling NTLMv1 usage in enterprise network . After that we mitigated LM hash usage on SMB and other communications. My question could be dumb but I want to know: If attacker got SAM database contents somehow ( via live OS, mimikatz and so on) , will that configuration help us to disable LM hash exposure or not?  what is recommended to configure endpoints in a way that it only store NTLM hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to change SAM file and it is not reasonable to make modifications on it. If you have physical access to machine, nothing will help you to stop adversary. LM and NTLM hash types must be inside SAM, by disabling LM hash exchange during communications is enough to stop "some kind of" hijack and cracking techniques but It will not disable or change SAM structure.